# Как вызвать suspend функцию библиотеки Kotlin из кода Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, асинхронность, kotlinx-coroutines

**Ситуация**

Есть корпоративная библиотека на Kotlin. В библиотеке есть основной метод, который в процессе работы обращается к suspend fun. Метод принимает только один аргумент и возвращает Boolean.
Библиотекой должны пользоваться разработчики на Java, соответственно, вызывать из Java-кода.

Основные асинхронные вызовы - это сетевое взаимодействие с помощью Ktor.

В данный момент пишу шаблон проекта для разработчиков-джавистов и пытаюсь сам использовать библиотеку из Java-кода.

**В чем проблема**

При вызове метода из кода Java он начинает требовать второй аргумент - континуацию и возвращать не Boolean, а Object.

В виде кода выгляит примерно так:

**Kotlin-библиотека:**

```
class MainClass(){ // Конструктор класса принимает некоторые агрументы, но это можно опустить в данной ситуации
  // Какие-то переменные, вспомогательные методы

  private suspend fun getResults(): Array<Result> { // Result - просто data class, ничего особенного.

    // Некоторые асинхронные вызовы

  }

  suspend fun mainFun(arg: ClassForParser): Boolean { // Принимает только один аргумент - класс, в который будет парситься JSON-строка в процессе

    // Код метода
    // Вызов getResults()

    return result
  }
}
```

**Вызов из java:**

```
public class SomeClass() {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Некоторый код, который корректно работает: собирает и вычисляет данные, компанует их перед отправкой в основной класс

    MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();

    Boolean result = mainClass.mainFun(ClassForParsing, Continuation) // Появилась континуация как второй аргумент.

    //Метод теперь возвращает Object, а не Boolean
  }
}
```

**Что удалось на данный момент**.

Удалось запустить метод, но вместо Boolean возвращает объект *kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics.CoroutineSingletons*

**Собственно, вопрос**

Что нужно сделать, чтобы метод запустился так, как я его задумывал? Где в моих знаниях был пробел, из-за которого такое получилось?

**Решение, которое не подойдет.**
Переписать либу на Java. Я не джавист, либа почти готова, а дедлайн близко. На это нет времени. Проще будет джавистов научить пользоваться либой на Kotlin.

Спасибо.

Comment: В Котлин есть совместимость с Java, но некоторые фичи в Котлин, такие как корутины, являются фичами Котлин. В Java с ними напрямую работать не слишком удобно. Есть ли у вас возможность внести изменения в Kotlin-библиотеку, чтобы адаптировать ее для использования в Java-коде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java нет концепции `suspend`-функций. Чтобы пользоваться библиотекой, написанной на Kotlin, из Java-кода, библиотеку необходимо для этого адаптировать.

Предположим, у вас есть такой `suspend`-метод в библиотеке:

```kotlin
suspend fun doSomething(): MyClass {
    ...
}
```

Эту функцию можно обернуть в `CompletableFuture` с помощью функции [`future`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8) из библиотеки [`kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8):

```kotlin
fun doSomethingAsync(): CompletableFuture<MyClass> =
    scope.future { doSomething() }
```

Тогда в Java-коде вам не нужно будет работать со всякими «континуациями», а будут знакомые `CompletableFuture`.

На английском Stackoverflow есть подобный вопрос: [Call Kotlin suspend function in Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672)

Comment: Спасибо.
Попробую ваш способ, расскажу как получилось

Comment: Метод сработал.
Только вместо scope нужно было GlobalScope записать, видимо синтаксис менялся.

Но в целом, большое спасибо, очень помогли

Comment: @АлександрОспенников, если ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, отметьте его галочкой.